# Switching from Google provisioning API to JSON service authorizing through oauth2

Tags: google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm just getting started porting my old code over to the new google apps json service but I'm not clear on the oauth.

I'm looking at:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites

It says:

> "Set up a new project in the Google APIs Console and activate Admin SDK service for this project. See the Google APIs Console Help in the upper right corner of the Console page for more information about creating your API project. "

My product gets installed at each client location.  Do I create the app using my key then distribute this to my customers or do I use their key in my app that runs at their site?  Do I also need to enable the admin SDK in addition to enabling API access?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I create the app using my key then distribute this to my customers or do I use their key in my app that runs at their site?

Do they have access to the source code? If true then it will be known to them.
Whether it is your key (an API project owner by you) or theirs depends on the kind of software you offer (tailored or common service (webapp?)) and who will be responsible of the quotas, billing (if needed) and maintenance.

> Do I also need to enable the admin SDK in addition to enabling API access?

Yes.

FYI:

- API projects can hold up to 20 accounts
- Users can own several projects (don't know how many)
- Projects can be shared with other users or Groups

Comment: Woa.  So if I use the same key and deploy to all the customers then all the installs will be subject to one quota?  The quota is determined by the key?  If that's the case, I'll go right past that daily quota easily!

Comment: Worse: Quotas are per project (projects can hold up to 20 accounts, an account have an associated key)

Said that, the default project quotas are quite nice for an organization. Admin SDK API have 20.0 requests/second/user (which you can adjust) and 2,000,000 requests/day (which you cannot change) limits and they let you beg for more xD

Comment: So if this tool runs at the customer location but is using my app key all the customers together will hit against my requests.  I'm still a little foggy on this, each of these customers have their own google domain.  Does the quota take this into account or is it still be application / account key?

Comment: Doesn't take it into account. And it's not per application/acount key. It's per project. Use 1 (or more) projects for each costumer so quotas are not shared between costumers, then decide who pays the bill for quota overuse. Account keys are just configuration items...